# Using two datasources in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, datasource

I'm using `Spring Boot 1.3.3` in my project with **one** database, now i want to use two databases with the **same schema** but **different connections**.

I want to use same repositories, entities and find the way to tell spring which datasource i want to use depending on the situation.

Comment: Use the Spring active profiles in application.yml

Comment: @Zubair I want to use both at the same time and depending on the situation in my service choose one or another.

Comment: @JeanCedron That's a complicated setup.  Not to dodge the question, but have you thought about using a messaging layer to faciliate this?  Decider App makes a decision as to which datasource to persist to.  Then it sends a message to a datasource specific queue for which a worker node reads and persists the data.  Just a thought...  I've done a few dual datasource apps but they were fully package separated with respect to entities, repositories, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If anyone has this problem, i've found the solution:

First your **application.properties** should look like this:

```
datasource:
primary:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/primary_db
    username: your_username
    password: your_password
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
secondary:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/secondary_db
    username: your_username
    password: your_password
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

After that, you have to create an enum with your databases:

```
public enum Database {
    PRIMARY,
    SECONDARY
}
```

Then, you create a ThreadLocal:

```
public class DatabaseThreadContext {

    private static final ThreadLocal<Database> current = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public static void setCurrentDatabase(Database database) {
        current.set(database);
    }

    public static Object getCurrentDatabase() {
        return current.get();
    }

}
```

Here comes the magic, you have to use **AbstractRoutingDataSource** which was implemented in Spring 2 back in 2007:

```
public class RoutingDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {

    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        return DatabaseThreadContext.getCurrentDatabase();
    }

}
```

Finally inject a Configuration in your Spring Boot App:

```
@Configuration
public class DatabaseRouter {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="datasource.primary")
    public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="datasource.secondary")
    public DataSource secondaryDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        Map<Object, Object> targetDatasources = new HashMap<Object, Object>(){{
            put(Database.SECONDARY, secondaryDataSource());
            put(Database.PRIMARY, primaryDataSource());
        }};
        RoutingDataSource routingDataSource = new RoutingDataSource();
        routingDataSource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(primaryDataSource());
        routingDataSource.setTargetDataSources(targetDatasources);
        routingDataSource.afterPropertiesSet();
        return routingDataSource;
    }

}
```

In every request, if you want to change between your databases you just use this function: `DatabaseThreadContext.setCurrentDatabase(Database.PRIMARY);`.

Also, you can have more than two databases at the same time.